# AnimationPlaybackController has only resume(), pause() and stop() methods

Tags: swift, animation, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

`AnimationPlaybackController` has only `resume()`, `pause()` and `stop()` methods in RealityKit.

```
func move(to:relativeTo:duration:timingFunction:)
```

**How to loop or repeat asset's animation**?

Answer (score 0):

#### You mean Transform Animation, not Asset one

You can infinitely loop or repeat a certain number of times an Asset Animation in RealityKit using **`playAnimation(_:transitionDuration:startsPaused:)`** instance method, but there's no loop options when you use methods like `move(to:relativeTo:duration:)` for Transform Animation.

```
model.move(to: .init(1.0), relativeTo: nil, 
                             duration: 10, 
                       timingFunction: .default).resume()  // No loop options
```

However, you can use `FromToByAnimation` object (it's available for iOS and visionOS), where `repeatMode` option determines how the animation repeats.

```
func loopingTranslation() {

    let matrix = Transform(matrix: float4x4( [1,0,0,0], 
                                             [0,1,0,0], 
                                             [0,0,1,0], 
                                             [0,2,0,1] ) )

    let def = FromToByAnimation(from: matrix, 
                            duration: 5, 
                          bindTarget: .transform, 
                          repeatMode: .cumulative)

    if let animation = try? AnimationResource.generate(with: def) {
        yourModel.playAnimation(animation)
    }
}
```